# Pathos processing pool recursion limit

Tags: python, recursion, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pathos

I've got a task I'm trying to parallelize with pathos. When I run a non parallel version, it runs just fine. However, running a pathos pool of 1 process causes a RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

For example:

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.ProcessPool(1)
def _worker(fx):
    return fx[0](fx[1],fx[2])
```

In my attempts to debug why this error is occuring, I've tried mapping a list of one object. This works without multiprocessing

```
>>> map(_worker, izip([t1.getValue], repeat(a_all), repeat(penalties)))
[-0.34375]
```

Where `t1.getValue` is the expensive function to be applied. I have an entire list of these expesive functions that are applied to the same two arguments. This is where the parallel processing comes in. However the following throws the error:

```
>>> pool.map(_worker, izip([t1.getValue], repeat(a_all), repeat(penalties)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What's interesting is that `getValue` is not recursive. I know that this sometimes occurs when the stack limit is reached.

How do I figure out what part of `getValue` is causing the error to get multiprocessing to work? I'm stuck because I don't know how to debug this from this point. Is it possible that this actually caused by a pickling error when passing data to processes? `getValue` does handle some large structures behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use sys.setrecursionlimit() to increase the limit of recursion, such as:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)
```

Comment: this is a horrible idea and addresses the symptom but not the problem